# Can't get CoreSpotlight to work properly on the Mac... sample code anyone?

Tags: macos, cocoa, corespotlight

Can someone point me to some sample code for using CoreSpotlight on the Mac? I can’t find a single sample code example (for mac, plenty of iOS ones out there). I have already successfully implemented CS on our iOS app.

Using code similar to what I used for iOS, I’m getting it to index the content, but it’s very minimal: it gives me the generic app icon for the content (rather than the custom thumbnail image I specify) and has no description, etc (on the Spotlight pane, the entire right side is blank).

Also, it's unclear to me what code I need to add to AppDelegate to handle the click on the spotlight data. I used `func application(_ application: NSApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler:) on iOS but this doesn't seem to get called on the Mac.

Here's the code I'm using to index the content:

```
        attributeSet.title = content.name
        attributeSet.contentDescription = content.description
        if let image = image {
            let cgImage = image.cgImage(forProposedRect: nil, context: nil, hints: nil)!
            let bitmapRep = NSBitmapImageRep(cgImage: cgImage)
            attributeSet.thumbnailData = bitmapRep.representation(using: NSBitmapImageRep.FileType.jpeg, properties: [:])!
        }
        let item = CSSearchableItem(uniqueIdentifier:content.uuid, domainIdentifier: "com.my.app.bundle.id", attributeSet: attributeSet)
        searchableIndex?.indexSearchableItems([item]) { error in
            if let error = error {
                NSLog("CoreSpotlight Indexing error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
```

And this is an example of what I get in Spotlight:
[image: spotlight screen shot]

A bit of sample code would clear this right up, Methinks.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but have you seen the sample project [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/231/)

Comment: Thanks. i'm back looking at this again after a couple weeks away. So it looks like my indexing is working but I need to add a QuickLook Preview to populate the right side of the Spotlight pane. I've followed the instructions in the video above (where they add it and everything magically and instantly works) but darned if I can get anything working. 

Also, Apple's sample code linked above, for mac, dosn't seem to be working at all.

Very frustrated at the moment.